# What connectors do I need for this water heater?

Tags: plumbing

Looking at replacing my water heater with [this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Reliance-6-6-SOMS-K-6-Gallon-Compact-Electric-Water-Heater/21061994?athcpid=21061994&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=RecentlyViewed&athieid=v0&athstid=CS002&athguid=466001f5-36c78c29-10a970c4349d94f7&athena=true). It has screw-on inlet/outlets. I want to connect to the old copper inlets/outlets with pex and Sharkbite fittings. What kind of connectors do I need at the water tank for these that will connect to pex?

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer has the manual available online. It gives a lot of detail, and does mention using both copper and PEX.

> **Step 7:**
>   1. Connect the water
>   supply
>   Determine the type of water pipes in
>   your home. Most homes use copper
>   water pipes, but some use CPVC or
>   cross-linked polyethylene (PEX). Use
>   fittings appropriate for the type of pipe
>   in your home. Do not use iron or PVC
>   pipe – they are not suitable for potable
>   water.
>   2.
>   Connect the cold water
>   supply using **3/4 inch
>   National Pipe Thread** “NPT”
>   to the cold water inlet nipple.
>   For ease of removing the water heater
>   for service or replacement, connect
>   the water pipes with a coupling
>   called a union. We recommend using
>   a dielectric-type union (available at
>   your local plumbing supplier ). Dielectric
>   unions can help prevent corrosion
>   caused by any electric currents
>   common in copper water pipes and
>   can help extend the life of the water
>   heater.
>   3. Connect the hot water supply
>   using 3/4 inch NPT to the hot
>   water outlet. Follow the same
>   connection guidelines as for the cold
>   water supply.

[Reliance Support Web Page](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Reliance-6-6-SOMS-K-6-Gallon-Compact-Electric-Water-Heater/21061994?athcpid=21061994&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=RecentlyViewed&athieid=v0&athstid=CS002&athguid=466001f5-36c78c29-10a970c4349d94f7&athena=true)

[Reliance Water Heater Installation Guide](http://www.reliancewaterheaters.com/media/66633/100263107-Reliance-Residential-Electric-6-year-Instruction-Manual.pdf)